# Call to method of static java.text.DateFormat not advisable?

Tags: java, static

I am receiving a *Find Bugs* error - **call to method of static java.text.DateFormat** and 
I don't know the reason why it's not good / advisable to be doing these things below.

```
private static final Date TODAY = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
private static final DateFormat yymmdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd"); 

private String fileName = "file_" + yymmdd.format(TODAY);
```

Comment: Call method aside, this code does look a bit suspect - `TODAY` will be a constant day, formatter is a final non-static?

Comment: Also TODAY may not always be "today", if for example this class is loaded and then the JVM is left to run until the next day - any logic relying on TODAY to be the current day will not work, unless you are accounting for this discrepancy.

Comment: @Peter - Yes, the program is being reset for every run.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

DateFormats are not thread-safe, meaning that they maintain an internal representation of state. Using them in a static context can yield some pretty strange bugs if multiple threads access the same instance simultaneously.

My suggestion would be to make your variables local to where you're using them instead of making them static properties of the class. It looks like you might be doing this when you're initializing the class, so you could do this in the constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String fileName;

    public MyClass() {
        final Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        final DateFormat yymmdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd"); 

        this.fileName = "file_" + yymmdd.format(TODAY);
    }
    ...
}
```

And if you need to use the formatter in multiple places, you might just make the pattern `static final` and create a new local `DateFormat` when needed:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final String FILENAME_DATE_PATTERN = "yyMMdd";

    public void myMethod() {
        final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_DATE_PATTERN);
        // do some formatting
    }
}
```

The [FindBugs documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#STCAL_INVOKE_ON_STATIC_DATE_FORMAT_INSTANCE) for the issue says:

> As the JavaDoc states, DateFormats are
>   inherently unsafe for multithreaded
>   use. The detector has found a call to
>   an instance of DateFormat that has
>   been obtained via a static field. This
>   looks suspicous.
>
> For more information on this see Sun
>   Bug #6231579 and Sun Bug #6178997.

And the [javadoc for DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) suggests:

> Date formats are not synchronized. It
>   is recommended to create separate
>   format instances for each thread. If
>   multiple threads access a format
>   concurrently, it must be synchronized
>   externally.

[Jack Leow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409657/call-to-method-of-static-java-text-dateformat-not-advisable/2409758#2409758) also has a good point about the semantics of your static use of "TODAY".

As an aside, I've actually seen this happen in a high-traffic production environment, and it's a very confusing thing to debug at first; so in my experience the FindBugs warning is actually a useful suggestion (unlike some other static analysis rules, which sometimes seem to be nitpicky).

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I think it's too expensive to create a SimpleDateFormat everytime myMethod() gets called.

Comment: @eradicus - Do you have performance metrics proving that it is "too expensive"? Unless you have observed it being a bottleneck for the application, I would prefer the local approach over cluttering the global scope with `static final`s. Obligatory Knuth: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Why isn't it enough that the variable is "final", i.e. constant? If it cannot change all threads should be able to share it, no? Or is it a question of race conditions for initialization?

Comment: `final` only means that the *reference* can't be reassigned - contents of the object the reference points to aren't guaranteed anything from the presence of `final`.

Answer (score 16):

[Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html) object that is thread safe.
It only does formatting though, not parsing.

If you can use commons-lang this might work well for you.

```
private static final Date TODAY = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
private static final FastDateFormat yymmdd = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyMMdd");

private String fileName = "file_" + yymmdd.format(TODAY);
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative that not has been mentioned is using ThreadLocal. See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-best-practices-dateformat-in.html for more info + performance comparison between the 3 options:

- Creating an instance each time
- Synchronising access
- Using ThreadLocal

Example of using ThreadLocal:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> DATE_FORMAT = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
DATE_FORMAT.get().format( TODAY )
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it's not

```
private static final DateFormat yymmdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
```

? That's what the error message indicates.

I think what it aims at is the fact that `DateFormat` is not thread safe, so having an instance as a static field indicates potential race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if FindBugs is complaining about this, but one problem I see with your code is that you're defining `TODAY` as a class level (static), constant (final) variable. This communicates the intent that you want `TODAY` to never change (I don't believe this is the case, since java.util.Dates are mutable, but that's another story).

Think about what happens if you application runs for multiple days? `TODAY` (unless you update it) will be referencing the day the application was started, not the current date. Are you sure this is what you meant?

This may not be a bug in your code at all, but the intent is not clear, and I believe that *may* be what FindBugs is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

It's not thread-safe, for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because format is not thread-safe?

(I have not seen what findbugs complain about, can you provide the 
warning text?)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this to go away by wrapping all the references to the DateFormat in a synchronize block - just make sure all calls are wrapped in the *same* synchronize object!

Comment: This might get rid of the FindBugs error, but wouldn't it be more logical to just new-up a local DateFormat when you need it?

Comment: @Rob, I guess that would depend on whether the synchronize was actually likely to block once in a while, or if it's just a formality to appease FindBugs.

Comment: True. I guess that synchronizing might be an alternative if the overhead of creating a new DateFormat is somehow affecting system performance, but I doubt that it would in most cases. Plus, if that was the case, it'd probably be a higher-load system, and synchronizing would impede the performance in a similar manner, I think.