# What does these FindBug messages show?

Tags: java, findbugs

Not every description from from http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html is clear to me. Sure, I can study the implementation but if somebody is more experienced then me, some explanation and examples would be great.

- Do you have some examples for UI_INHERITANCE_UNSAFE_GETRESOURCE when this is getting a problem?
- In BX_UNBOXED_AND_COERCED_FOR_TERNARY_OPERATOR I don't see the problem either. If one type is "bigger" then the other, for example int and float, then the result is float. If its Integer and Float its the wrapper Float too. That's what I expect.
- Does the GC_UNRELATED_TYPES really help to find errors? Isn't it the job of the compiler to check, if--taking the given example--`Foo` can't go into a `Collection<String>`.
- Does HE_SIGNATURE_DECLARES_HASHING_OF_UNHASHABLE_CLASS mean something like `bla(Foo f){hashtable.put(f);}`, where ´Foo´ is not hashable? Does FingBugs "see" the subclasses too?
- NP_GUARANTEED_DEREF_ON_EXCEPTION_PATH is stronger "wrong" then NP_ALWAYS_NULL_EXCEPTION? Why two error cases and with NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_EXCEPTION even one more? Sounds very similar to me.
- What is an example of SIO_SUPERFLUOUS_INSTANCEOF? Something like `foo(String s){if (s intenceof String) ...`. This does a null check too, but this is not the test here...
- NN_NAKED_NOTIFY. I my opinion the description is not clear. A change of the state is not necessary. If I use new Object() to wait and notify on I don't change the object state. Or is state the lock-state? I don't get it.
- SP_SPIN_ON_FIELD. Can this really happen that a compiler will move this outside from a loop? This doesn't make sense to me because from outside a Thread can always change the values. And if the variable is `volatile` the JVM can't cache the value. So what's the meaning?
- That is the difference between STCAL_STATIC_CALENDAR_INSTANCE and STCAL_INVOKE_ON_STATIC_CALENDAR_INSTANCE or STCAL_INVOKE_ON_STATIC_DATE_FORMAT_INSTANCE/STCAL_STATIC_SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT_INSTANCE?
- Why is XXXX.class in WL_USING_GETCLASS_RATHER_THAN_CLASS_LITERAL better then getClass()? A getClass() in a superclass called from the subclass will always return the Class object from the subclass which is good I think.
- What exactly does EQ_UNUSUAL do? It should check that the argument is of the same type of the class itself but it does't?
- Did you ever had problems with breaks? Is there real value with SF_SWITCH_FALLTHROUGH? Sounds to strong for me.
- No idea what TQ_EXPLICIT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE_VALUE_REACHES_ALWAYS_SINK and TQ_EXPLICIT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE_VALUE_REACHES_NEVER_SINK could be.

Answer (score 8):

I can comment on some of the FindBugs descriptions you mention, based on my experience and testing, without consulting the FindBugs source code.

- UI_INHERITANCE_UNSAFE_GETRESOURCE:
  If you use `this.getClass().getResource(...)` with a relative URI, that URI is
  resolved with respect to the class of `this`. When a subclass resides in a
  different package and you get the resource for a subclass, you end up looking
  at a different place (relative to the subclass). I know of examples where a class looks for a resource known to reside in the same package, by calling `getResource()` with a relative URI containing only the filename. If that class where to use `this.getClass()` instead of `ClassName.class`, and the actual instance is of a subclass, the resource would not be found.
- BX_UNBOXED_AND_COERCED_FOR_TERNARY_OPERATOR:
  This talks about boxed number types, like `Integer` and `Float`, as
  opposed to primitive number types, like `int` and `float`. For
  primitives, your expectation is correct: In `boolean ? int : float`
  the `int` is coerced to `float`. But for wrapped numbers, something
  unexpected happens: In `boolean ? Integer : Float`, the `Integer` is
  unboxed and coerced to `float`. I would have expected the objects
  to be returned unchanged, like in
  `boolean ? (Number)Integer : Float`.

  ```
  boolean b = Boolean.TRUE;
  final Integer i = 123456789;
  final Float f = 1.0f;
  final Number x = b ? i : f;
  System.out.println("wrapped coerced: " + x); // 1.23456792E8
  final Number y = b ? (Number) i : f;
  System.out.println("wrapped uncoerced: " + y); // 123456789
  ```
- GC_UNRELATED_TYPES: FindBugs knows
  about some collection methods that could
  not be generified for Java 1.5, like
  `Collection.contains(Object)`. Here,
  the argument must be of type
  `Object`, because otherwise existing
  source code might break. But any object
  not of the collection's type is sure
  to be not contained, so asking for
  containment of an `Integer` in a
  `String` collection probably is a
  bug.

  ```
  Collection<String> coll = new ArrayList<String>();
  System.out.println(coll.contains(42));
  ```
- HE_SIGNATURE_DECLARES_HASHING_OF_UNHASHABLE_CLASS:
  ?
- NP_GUARANTEED_DEREF_ON_EXCEPTION_PATH:
  ?
- SIO_SUPERFLUOUS_INSTANCEOF: ?
- NN_NAKED_NOTIFY: ?
- SP_SPIN_ON_FIELD: If you spin on a
  field that is not `volatile`, the JIT
  is free to optimize the code (by
  moving the read out of the loop) as
  long as the thread executing the loop
  produces the same result, without
  taking into account the existence and
  actions of other threads. That's why
  there is a `volatile` keyword. I know of no example where this actually lead to a bug.
- STCAL_STATIC_CALENDAR_INSTANCE: ?
- WL_USING_GETCLASS_RATHER_THAN_CLASS_LITERAL:
  In the FindBugs example, the method
  synchronizes on `getClass()` to
  access a static member of its class.
  A subclass will synchronize on the
  subclass, and so the superclass and
  the subclass can enter the
  synchronized block at the same time because they synchronize on different monitors,
  leading to a race condition.
- EQ_UNUSUAL: ?
- SF_SWITCH_FALLTHROUGH: This helps me
  sometimes, because I tend to miss the
  `break`. Interestingly, in a test
  case just performed, I got in addition to this
  FindBugs message the message
  SF_DEAD_STORE_DUE_TO_SWITCH_FALLTHROUGH.
- TQ_EXPLICIT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE_VALUE_REACHES_ALWAYS_SINK:
  ?

Comment: for the STCAL_STATIC_CALENDAR_INSTANCE here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/2409657/579646